# How do I wire a new light and switch using power from an old fixture?

Tags: wiring, renovation

I'm wiring a new light and single pole switch to using power from an old fixture.  The old fixture has 2 white wires and one red wire and a bare ground.  The existing wiring goes to a couple of outlets; some more lights in the area, and then to a single pole switch.  I have modern 14-2 wire (1 white, 1 black, 1 ground).  I'm assuming the red wire is switched, which I wouldn't want to connect to.  That leaves the 2 white wires.  Not sure what to do at this [image]point.

Comment: The two whites are your neutrals and can consider them as the same wire.  Will need to find a different junction box with power from the breaker.  Connecting at that box will cause all new devices to be controlled by the switch.  With two whites, there should be another coloured wire in that box.  White are paired with a black  or a red and black wire(plus ground)

Comment: Unless you are using conduit(probably if using conduit) you should have two blacks hidden(not shown in the picture) in that box.  One for one white and one for the white and red wires, not counting the black and white bent over the box.

Comment: You need to show us the wires in the back of the box.  You need always-hot and neutral for your extension.  Obviously "always-hot" doesn't go to a lamp, or it would be always-on. **You got lucky that this was a "switch loop"**. Had it been "power from the switch", which it is half the time, this would have failed.  So next time, learn the wiring before you run your extension!

Answer (score 2):

### You made a mistake and got lucky. *But learn the lesson!*

The lesson is, when you are looking at a group of switches and the lights they control, **you need to map out the circuit BEFORE trying to tap it**.

The reason is, you want always-hot and neutral for your extension.  In any group of lamps and switches, that only exists in one place - and you never know where it'll be until you map the circuit.  Here. Consider this 3-way circuit.

[image]

Where can you tap that?  Only at the left switch.  If you try to tap the lamp or 2nd switch, you lose.   OK, how about this 3-way?

[image]

Oh! On that one, only at the lamp!   See, you don't know til you open up the boxes and look.

---

Now on a "switch loop", a switch installed after 2011 should have a /3 cable which brings always-hot and neutral to the switch.  In that case you can tap either the lamp or the switch.  But that's the exception, not the rule. **You have to look**.

Answer (score 0):

The two whites are your neutrals and can be connected together.

The red comes from the switch and it is switchable hot. That combo is connected to the lamp.

Then you have more wires B+W+G where it is not clear where do they go.

If you have more lights on that circuit, then they are possibly for that.

If you connect the black to the red it will power up other lights with switch on/off. At the switch (not shown) there should be an always hot wire.

Comment: Thanks.  Issue resolved.  Found a sneaky black wire deep in the farthest reaches of that 4" diameter...3" deep...okay, that is embarrassing.

Comment: @TryingMyBestRenoGuy You are welcome, I did nothing other than made you look